# Why are we using liquid?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am new to Shopify and Liquid. While reading I came up with an doubt that which of the two options are good:

If site is hosted on Shopify i.e. Shopify is a server:

1. Client request to server and server renders the HTML pages.
2. Client request to server and server converts liquid files to HTML pages and then renders.

clearly 2) will take time.

I have read the use of liquid is that we can use logic there. But still are we not taking extra time to render the page. So, why we are doing this?

Answer (score 0):

When you let Shopify turn Liquid constructs into HTML, it takes the templates and data from the servers and securely turns them into strings of HTML. It then renders complete HTML in your browser.

1. You cannot screw up the data since you have no access to it except via correct and allowed controls built in to Shopify
2. they can render those strings faster than you ever could, so speed is not really an issue

They let you screw up your page load time in plenty of other ways, like non-optimized images, non-minimized CSS and JS... but for the most part, you should be very happy Shopify uses Liquid. It means you can focus on your job without worrying about petty things you should not be worried about. Plus you get global CDN for assets, making your shop fast in all corners of the wired globe, something you could not do on your own, cheaply.